# Could you fix the Python init function?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this Python code...

```
class clss:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.data = d
```

But every time I run it, I get this error...

> AttributeError: 'clss' object has no attribute 'data'

How do I fix the error?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The code you posted only defines a class; it doesn't throw that error. And an error message without context is not useful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  We need to see the calling code (that is, a minimal version of the calling code) to understand the error completely.  However, pay attention to the error message.  You're trying to `self.data` from `data`.  Where is the latter `data` variable coming from?  Did you mean to use `self.data = d` instead?

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer, if it helped you to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `data` is not defined anywhere, hence it cannot be assigned to `self.data`.

You'll want to pass `data` as an argument to `__init__` instead of `d`:

```
class clss:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
```

Comment: I fixed the variable data into d